# String is displayed as Cyrillic - wrong charset?

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, json

I Have a problem with displaying a value out of a decoded JSON. The JSON is a response from a Russian API.

The value inside the JSON = Object268

But at first it displayed as: ÐžÐ±ÑŠÐµÐºÑ‚ 268

After adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` to my html it became: Объект 268

What charset do I have to use to just get Object268 (non Cyrillic)?

EDIT:
I just want to save some data in my database, I can't read Cyrillic and in the api response I can read the values, so I like to store them like that.
API response: http://api.worldoftanks.ru/2.0/encyclopedia/tanks/?application_id=171745d21f7f98fd8878771da1000a31

php code:

```
$url="http://api.worldoftanks.ru/2.0/encyclopedia/tanks/?application_id=171745d21f7f98fd8878771da1000a31";
            $response = curl($url);
            $json = json_decode($response, true);
            echo ("<br /><p>Tanks: </p><br />");
            $id=0;

            foreach($json['data'] as $key){
                echo ("ID = ".$key['tank_id']." tier = ".$key['level']." tank = ".$key['name_i18n']."<br />");
            }
```

Comment: `Объект 268` seems to be correct cryllic... so what's your problem?

Comment: I don't want it to be displayed as Cyrillic, I'll add it in my question to prevent confusion.

Comment: Try `utf8_decode()` your string. For what ever reason you want to get a string in wrong charset...

Comment: Please show actual code that demonstrates the problem. To being with, what does the JSON data actually contain, and are you sure about that? Latin letters don’t get converted to Cyrillic on their own, on in JSON decode. Some software, not even mentioned or alluded to in the question, seems to be performing *transliteration*.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER this results in: ?????? 268

Comment: may be your api give to you local json output with traslation. check the possibility to get english version. encoding doest matter here

Answer (score 0):

use 'name' instead of 'name_i18n'

```
echo ("ID = ".$key['tank_id']." tier = ".$key['level']." tank = ".$key['name']."<br />");
```

also, you can parse the output of name, deleting everything before colon `:` to get only the name in English

Answer (score 0):

Reset the character set using PHP code below:

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

or check the below:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-set-content-encoding-type-header/

Comment: Makes the result: ÐžÐ±ÑŠÐµÐºÑ‚ 268